# Protected shared memory?

Tags: c, api, memory, memory-management, shared-memory

I want to use shared memory, but i want only my application instances to be able to access this memory, somehow want to protect it from accessing by other applications...
I am coding in C on Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CreateFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with specific `LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`.

Comment: I see that you can configure different user groups access but thats now what i am looking for...

Comment: +1 Windows security is the answer. If it's not what you are looking for, that's just tough.

Comment: lets say i start two instances of my application, i want only these two instances to access the shared memory, any other applications must not be allowed to access it... Anyone know code example of this ?

Comment: I don't think that's how security works. Never mind file mappings, do you know that another process can read all the memory in your process?